# SQL aggregate functions, inner join

Tags: sql

I am working on writing a sql to get the SID and SNAME. In this task, I need to count which team win the max number of League and find out the SID.

- Leagues(LID, CHAMPION_TID)
- LID: League ID ; CHAMPION_TID: champion team ID
- SUPPORT(SID, LID)
- SPONSORS(SID, SNAME)
- PRIMARY KEY: LID,SID

Now, I can find out which team win the max number of League through the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(y.cham) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CHAMPION_TID, COUNT(L.CHAMPION_TID) AS cham 
     FROM 
         LEAGUES L 
     GROUP BY 
         L.CHAMPION_TID) y, LEAGUES L 
WHERE
    y.CHAMPION_TID = L.CHAMPION_TID;
```

I am confusing in the following step. My idea get the LID, then use the join table to display SID and SNAME. But I suck in this step.

```
SELECT L.LID, MAX(y.cham) 
FROM 
    (SELECT CHAMPION_TID, COUNT(L.CHAMPION_TID) AS cham 
     FROM LEAGUES L 
     GROUP BY L.CHAMPION_TID) y, LEAGUES L 
WHERE 
    y.CHAMPION_TID = L.CHAMPION_TID
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to find the Sponsor ID and Sponsor Name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sp.SID,
    sp.SNAME
FROM
    LEAGUES l3
INNER JOIN support s ON
    l3.LID = s.LID
INNER JOIN SPONSORS sp ON
    s.SID = sp.SID
WHERE
    l3.CHAMPION_TID IN (
    SELECT
        l2.CHAMPION_TID
    FROM
        LEAGUES l2
    GROUP BY
        l2.CHAMPION_TID
    HAVING
        count(l2.CHAMPION_TID) = (
            SELECT
                count(l1.CHAMPION_TID)
            FROM
                LEAGUES l1
            GROUP BY
                l1.CHAMPION_TID
            ORDER BY
                count(l1.CHAMPION_TID) DESC 
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY 
        ) 
    );
```

It finds the count of `CHAMPION_TID` in `LEAGUES`, orders it by `desc` (such that the highest count is always on top), then uses it to find the associated `CHAMPION_TID`. It handles ties for `max(count(CHAMPION_TID))` as well :)

If `fetch first 1 row only` does not work, you can use `select top 1 l1.CHAMPION_TID..`.

Here is a [working demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Wtv1VUsyXrGdjHaPNBqqT/2) using Postgres.

Comment: the record may have more than one, because they may win the same number of champions. Sorry for the question is not clear and I show a part of the table only.

Comment: and I am using oracle database therefore I use fetch first 1 row only. Btw thx for the reminder.

Comment: @jay I have updated the answer accordingly, working demo link updated as well.